# How specify a path in Java shortcut?

Tags: 16.04, permissions, java

I am currently trying to use HERO Designer, a Java program, on Ubuntu 16.04. All other Java programs work as expected (i. e. I double click on them and they start without issue).

- If I run it from the command line (`java -jar HD6.jar`) everything works fine.
- If I double click on it, it locks up. The splash screen comes up and it stops a few moments later. When executed by double clicking the program starts, then hangs on the splash screen.

  According to the developer, this means I don't have write permissions. I looked in *Properties > Permissions*. I am the owner. The owner and group have read/write access, and the executable flag is checked. I also created a bash script that just runs the above line with the same results.

The result of the `ps aux | grep HD6` is:

```
daniel   13216  1.0  2.6 5019752 214316 ?      Sl   19:28   0:18 /usr/bin/java -jar /home/daniel/Programs/HERODesigner/HD6.jar
```

I'm opening with "OpenJDK Java 8 Runtime". Other Java programs run without issue by double clicking the icon. Any suggestions?

Comment: When you double click and the application lauches, it runs of course with the permissions as you detailed. Running from the command line should be no different, unless a different java JVM is being run with different env variables, if you are running indeed as the same user. First off then - what command are you using to launch from the command line ? Also, what is the result of `whereis java` ? You could then create a `.desktop` file with the approripate command

Comment: Creating a link didn't change anything. The command I'm using is "java -jar HD6.jar" (without the quotes).  The result of "whereis java" is "java: /usr/bin/java /usr/share/java /usr/share/man/man1/java.1.gz". I'm uisng openjdk "1.8.0_121".

Comment: How did you set up being able to run JARs by double-clicking by the way / what steps, method

Comment: Browsed to the jar file, right click on it, set the execute flag to true in the Permissions tab, and select "OpenJDK Java 8 Runtime" in the Open With tab.

Comment: I should note that I get the splash screen for the program when I double click on it.

Comment: Apologies I had to go test that... so you get the splash screen and it hangs there (or soon after)? Whilst it's hanging, if you open a terminal and do `ps aux | grep HD6.jar` you should be able to see what the actual command is running, as well as the user, etc; please add that output to the main description

Comment: Tried the above. It didn't make a difference.

Comment: you tried all of the above? (the top two answers look the least helpful to me)

Comment: That is correct. I tried all the above. I installed the openjdk 8 and other java programs work fine. I have not simply tried reinstalling Hero Designer. That will be my next step.

Comment: Reinstalling didn't make a difference.

Comment: What was the working directory when you ran `java -jar HD6.jar`? What happens when you run `cd / && java -jar /home/daniel/Programs/HERODesigner/HD6.jar` and `cd / && xdg-open /home/daniel/Programs/HERODesigner/HD6.jar`?

Comment: The working directory: /home/daniel/Programs/HERODesigner
The result of the two commands is the same as double clicking.
I will try creating a .desktop file, including the path.

Comment: That worked. I will write up a full answer.

Comment: If you have a solution, please post it as an answer instead of in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the shortcut did not include a path. You will have to manually create a .desktop file.

1. Right click on the desktop, New Document -> Empty Document.
2. Open the "Untitled Document" with your preferred text editor and enter the following, modified to your specific situation.

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Version=6.0
   Name=HERO Designer
   Comment=HERO Designer Build 20170109
   Exec=bash -c "cd /path/to/your/HERODesigner/folder && java -jar HD6.jar"
   Icon=/path/to/your/HERODesigner/folder/hdlogo.png
   Terminal=false
   Type=Application
   Categories=Games;Application;
   Path=/path/to/HERODesigner/folder
   ```
3. Save the file.
4. Rename the file "HERO Designer.desktop".
5. Right click on the "HERO Designer.desktop", click on the Permissions tab, and put a check in the "Allow executing file as program", close the window

You should now have a HERO Designer desktop icon. Double click and it should start up the program.